# SQL moving average

Tags: sql, hive, moving-average

How do you create a moving average in SQL?

Current table:

```
Date             Clicks 
2012-05-01       2,230
2012-05-02       3,150
2012-05-03       5,520
2012-05-04       1,330
2012-05-05       2,260
2012-05-06       3,540
2012-05-07       2,330
```

Desired table or output:

```
Date             Clicks    3 day Moving Average
2012-05-01       2,230
2012-05-02       3,150
2012-05-03       5,520          4,360
2012-05-04       1,330          3,330
2012-05-05       2,260          3,120
2012-05-06       3,540          3,320
2012-05-07       2,330          3,010
```

Comment: What database system are you using?

Comment: @BrianWebster: he said that in a comment to my (now deleted) post: He is using **Hive**. But you removed the tag for it.

Comment: Ok, fixed - I honestly didn't realize that was a database system

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**One way to do this is to join on the same table a few times.**

```
select
 (Current.Clicks 
  + isnull(P1.Clicks, 0)
  + isnull(P2.Clicks, 0)
  + isnull(P3.Clicks, 0)) / 4 as MovingAvg3
from
 MyTable as Current
 left join MyTable as P1 on P1.Date = DateAdd(day, -1, Current.Date)
 left join MyTable as P2 on P2.Date = DateAdd(day, -2, Current.Date)
 left join MyTable as P3 on P3.Date = DateAdd(day, -3, Current.Date)
```

Adjust the DateAdd component of the ON-Clauses to match whether you want your moving average to be strictly from the past-through-now or days-ago through days-ahead.

- This works nicely for situations where you need a moving average over only a few data points.
- This is not an optimal solution for moving averages with more than a few data points.

Comment: left join those.  (see the first two have none)

Comment: Isn't doing 4 joins going to be a pretty costly operation for large tables?

Comment: Depends on the data, but in my experience this is a pretty speedy operation.

Answer (score 19):

This is an Evergreen Joe Celko question.
I ignore which DBMS platform is used. But in any case Joe was able to answer more than 10 years ago with standard SQL.

> [Joe Celko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joe_Celko) SQL Puzzles and Answers citation: 
>   "That last update attempt suggests that we could use the predicate to
>   construct a query that would give us a moving average:"

```
SELECT S1.sample_time, AVG(S2.load) AS avg_prev_hour_load
FROM Samples AS S1, Samples AS S2
WHERE S2.sample_time
BETWEEN (S1.sample_time - INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
AND S1.sample_time
GROUP BY S1.sample_time;
```

> Is the extra column or the query approach better? The query is
>   technically better because the UPDATE approach will denormalize the
>   database. However, if the historical data being recorded is not going
>   to change and computing the moving average is expensive, you might
>   consider using the column approach.

MS SQL Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #TestDW
( Date1 datetime,
  LoadValue Numeric(13,6)
);

INSERT INTO #TestDW VALUES('2012-06-09' , '3.540' );
INSERT INTO #TestDW VALUES('2012-06-08' , '2.260' );
INSERT INTO #TestDW VALUES('2012-06-07' , '1.330' );
INSERT INTO #TestDW VALUES('2012-06-06' , '5.520' );
INSERT INTO #TestDW VALUES('2012-06-05' , '3.150' );
INSERT INTO #TestDW VALUES('2012-06-04' , '2.230' );
```

*SQL Puzzle query:*

```
SELECT S1.date1,  AVG(S2.LoadValue) AS avg_prev_3_days
FROM #TestDW AS S1, #TestDW AS S2
WHERE S2.date1
    BETWEEN DATEADD(d, -2, S1.date1 )
    AND S1.date1
GROUP BY S1.date1
order by 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info - but I'm having a hard time translating this to see how it solves the question. Can you give the query you would use for the table in the question?

Comment: This is even better as it can be modified to find out Moving average of N months..

Answer (score 3):

```
select t2.date, round(sum(ct.clicks)/3) as avg_clicks
from
(select date from clickstable) as t2,
(select date, clicks from clickstable) as ct
where datediff(t2.date, ct.date) between 0 and 2
group by t2.date
```

Example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84eddd/7).

Obviously you can change the interval to whatever you need. You could also use count() instead of a magic number to make it easier to change, but that will also slow it down.

Comment: Your first two entries are 1- and 2-day averages.  The question asks for those entries to be `NULL`.

Answer (score 2):

General template for rolling averages that scales well for large data sets

```
WITH moving_avg AS (
  SELECT 0 AS [lag] UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS [lag] UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS [lag] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS [lag] --ETC
)
SELECT
  DATEADD(day,[lag],[date]) AS [reference_date],
  [otherkey1],[otherkey2],[otherkey3],
  AVG([value1]) AS [avg_value1],
  AVG([value2]) AS [avg_value2]
FROM [data_table]
CROSS JOIN moving_avg
GROUP BY [otherkey1],[otherkey2],[otherkey3],DATEADD(day,[lag],[date])
ORDER BY [otherkey1],[otherkey2],[otherkey3],[reference_date];
```

And for weighted rolling averages:

```
WITH weighted_avg AS (
  SELECT 0 AS [lag], 1.0 AS [weight] UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS [lag], 0.6 AS [weight] UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS [lag], 0.3 AS [weight] UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS [lag], 0.1 AS [weight] --ETC
)
SELECT
  DATEADD(day,[lag],[date]) AS [reference_date],
  [otherkey1],[otherkey2],[otherkey3],
  AVG([value1] * [weight]) / AVG([weight]) AS [wavg_value1],
  AVG([value2] * [weight]) / AVG([weight]) AS [wavg_value2]
FROM [data_table]
CROSS JOIN weighted_avg
GROUP BY [otherkey1],[otherkey2],[otherkey3],DATEADD(day,[lag],[date])
ORDER BY [otherkey1],[otherkey2],[otherkey3],[reference_date];
```

Comment: interesting approach for **weighted**. Wouldn't work (well) for more discrete time points (timestamp rather date) though

Comment: @msciwoj Outside of academic exercises, what purpose would a fixed weight rolling average over non-uniform intervals have? Wouldn't you either histo the data first or calculate weight as a function of interval size?

Comment: by all means uniform. You just throw to the appropriate weight bucket depending on the distance from the current time point. For instance "take weight=1 for datapoints within 24hrs from current datapoint; weight=0.5 for datapoints within 48hrs…". That case it matters how much consecutive datapoints (like 6:12am and 11:48pm ) are distant from each other…  A use case I can think of would be an attempt to smooth the histogram wherever datapoints are not dense enough

Answer (score 2):

```
select *
        , (select avg(c2.clicks) from #clicks_table c2 
            where c2.date between dateadd(dd, -2, c1.date) and c1.date) mov_avg
from #clicks_table c1
```

Answer (score 1):

assume x is the value to be averaged and xDate is the date value:

SELECT avg(x) from myTable WHERE xDate BETWEEN dateadd(d, -2, xDate) and xDate

Answer (score 1):

Use a different join predicate:

```
SELECT current.date
       ,avg(periods.clicks)
FROM current left outer join current as periods
       ON current.date BETWEEN dateadd(d,-2, periods.date) AND periods.date
GROUP BY current.date HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

The having statement will prevent any dates without at least N values from being returned.

Comment: This will not show the May 1 and May 2 rows, which the questioner wants to see `NULL`s for.

Answer (score 1):

In hive, maybe you could try

```
select date, clicks, avg(clicks) over (order by date rows between 2 preceding and current row) as moving_avg from clicktable;
```

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose, I'd like to create an auxiliary/dimensional date table like

```
create table date_dim(date date, date_1 date, dates_2 date, dates_3 dates ...)
```

while `date` is the key, `date_1` for this day, `date_2` contains this day and the day before; `date_3`...

Then you can do the equal join in hive.

Using a view like:

```
select date, date               from date_dim
union all
select date, date_add(date, -1) from date_dim
union all
select date, date_add(date, -2) from date_dim
union all
select date, date_add(date, -3) from date_dim
```

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER** but an enhanced code sample of **Diego Scaravaggi**'s answer. I am posting it as answer as the comment section is insufficient. Note that I have parameter-ized the period for Moving aveage.

```
declare @p int = 3
declare @t table(d int, bal float)
insert into @t values
(1,94),
(2,99),
(3,76),
(4,74),
(5,48),
(6,55),
(7,90),
(8,77),
(9,16),
(10,19),
(11,66),
(12,47)

select a.d, avg(b.bal)
from
       @t a
       left join @t b on b.d between a.d-(@p-1) and a.d
group by a.d
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--@p1 is period of moving average, @01 is offset

declare @p1 as int
declare @o1 as int
set @p1 = 5;
set @o1 = 3;

with np as(
select *, rank() over(partition by cmdty, tenor order by markdt) as r
from p_prices p1
where
1=1 
)
, x1 as (
select s1.*, avg(s2.val) as avgval from np s1
inner join np s2 
on s1.cmdty = s2.cmdty and s1.tenor = s2.tenor
and s2.r between s1.r - (@p1 - 1) - (@o1) and s1.r - (@o1)
group by s1.cmdty, s1.tenor, s1.markdt, s1.val, s1.r
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your expected result (output) shows classic "simple moving (rolling) average" for 3 days. Because, for example, the first triple of numbers by definition gives:

```
ThreeDaysMovingAverage = (2.230 + 3.150 + 5.520) / 3 = 3.6333333
```

but you expect `4.360` and it's confusing.

Nevertheless, I suggest the following solution, which uses window-function `AVG`. This approach is much more efficient (clear and less resource-intensive) than `SELF-JOIN` introduced in other answers (and I'm surprised that no one has given a better solution).

```
-- Oracle-SQL dialect 
with
  data_table as (
     select date '2012-05-01' AS dt, 2.230 AS clicks from dual union all
     select date '2012-05-02' AS dt, 3.150 AS clicks from dual union all
     select date '2012-05-03' AS dt, 5.520 AS clicks from dual union all
     select date '2012-05-04' AS dt, 1.330 AS clicks from dual union all
     select date '2012-05-05' AS dt, 2.260 AS clicks from dual union all
     select date '2012-05-06' AS dt, 3.540 AS clicks from dual union all
     select date '2012-05-07' AS dt, 2.330 AS clicks from dual  
  ),
  param as (select 3 days from dual)
select
   dt     AS "Date",
   clicks AS "Clicks",

   case when rownum >= p.days then 
       avg(clicks) over (order by dt
                          rows between p.days - 1 preceding and current row)
   end    
          AS "3 day Moving Average"
from data_table t, param p;
```

You see that `AVG` is wrapped with `case when rownum >= p.days then` to force `NULL`s in first rows, where "3 day Moving Average" is meaningless.

Answer (score -1):

We can apply Joe Celko's **"dirty" left outer join** method (as cited above by Diego Scaravaggi) to answer the question as it was asked.

```
declare @ClicksTable table  ([Date] date, Clicks int)
insert into @ClicksTable
    select '2012-05-01', 2230 union all
    select '2012-05-02', 3150 union all
    select '2012-05-03', 5520 union all
    select '2012-05-04', 1330 union all
    select '2012-05-05', 2260 union all
    select '2012-05-06', 3540 union all
    select '2012-05-07', 2330
```

This query:

```
SELECT
    T1.[Date],
    T1.Clicks,
    -- AVG ignores NULL values so we have to explicitly NULLify
    -- the days when we don't have a full 3-day sample
    CASE WHEN count(T2.[Date]) < 3 THEN NULL
        ELSE AVG(T2.Clicks) 
    END AS [3-Day Moving Average] 
FROM @ClicksTable T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN @ClicksTable T2
    ON T2.[Date] BETWEEN DATEADD(d, -2, T1.[Date]) AND T1.[Date]
GROUP BY T1.[Date]
```

Generates the requested output:

```
Date             Clicks    3-Day Moving Average
2012-05-01       2,230
2012-05-02       3,150
2012-05-03       5,520          4,360
2012-05-04       1,330          3,330
2012-05-05       2,260          3,120
2012-05-06       3,540          3,320
2012-05-07       2,330          3,010
```